# Laravel request file upload with content-type won't work

Tags: laravel, file, upload, content-type

When I remove content-type from Postman laravel request has the file, but if I add any content type in headers it is null? Problem is that browsers add content-type,and I can not exclude them to make it work? Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably get the Content-Type from the UploadedFile instead:

```
$request->file('form_input_name')->getClientMimeType();
```

The content-type of the entire request will be set to something like `multipart encoding` when you send a file with Postman.

I hope this helps.

Comment: When i call $request->file('form_input_name') it is always null if header content-type is on. I checked, file is exists in /tmp folder for sometime,when i call this endpoint, but not in request. :(

Comment: That's possible, I don't know. Don't set the Content-Type in Postman. How are you doing the file upload in Postman? I usually do POST request, body, form-data, file upload. This way postman will automatically set the correct content-type for you, like you would have a <form method="post"> submission from the browser with <input type="file">.